# Syntax error in constructor declaration: '{' expected

Tags: java

I dont get what i did wrong for this constructor:

```
  public class Student(String first_name, String last_name, int home1, int home2,int quiz1, int quiz2, int quiz3, int exam1, int exam2)
  {
    fname=first_name;
    lname=last_name;
    hw1_grade=home1;
    hw2_grade=home2;
    quiz1_grade=quiz1;
    quiz2_grade=quiz2;
    quiz3_grade=quiz3; 
    exam1_grade=exam1;
    exam2_grade=exam2;
  }
```

The compiler says: '{' expected.
Also: < Identifier > expected it says this error over and over

Comment: That's not a constructor.  It's a malformed class declaration.  Is this supposed to be its own class declaration, or is this inside an actual `Student` class?

Comment: inside a student class i shouldve included that into the program

Comment: remove the word 'class' from the first line. Constructor should be just public Student(......)

Comment: Thats what i had intially but then the compiler just says its an invalid method declaration

Comment: Is it inside a `student` class or a `Student` class?  A constructor has to be named the same as the class.  Please [edit] your question to show the enclosing class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are declared **inside** the class definition. So you define the call first, and then inside the class definition, you implement your constructor:

```
public class Student {
    //fields
    String fname;
    String lname;
    //... etc.

    //here you declare your constructor, like so:
    public Student(String first_name, String last_name, int home1, int home2,int quiz1, int quiz2, int quiz3, int exam1, int exam2)
      {
            fname=first_name;
            lname=last_name;
            hw1_grade=home1;
            hw2_grade=home2;
            quiz1_grade=quiz1;
            quiz2_grade=quiz2;
            quiz3_grade=quiz3; 
            exam1_grade=exam1;
            exam2_grade=exam2;
      }
}
```

Also, on a side note, these are way too many parameters for a constructor in my opinion. Why not include only the most essential ones (first name, last name, etc.) and then set exam grades using setter methods?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Student {
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int hw1_grade;
    private int hw2_grade;
    private int quiz1_grade;
    private int quiz2_grade;
    private int quiz3_grade;
    private int exam1_grade;
    private int exam2_grade;

    public Student(String first_name, String last_name, int home1, int home2, int quiz1, int quiz2, int quiz3,
            int exam1, int exam2) {
        fname = first_name;
        lname = last_name;
        hw1_grade = home1;
        hw2_grade = home2;
        quiz1_grade = quiz1;
        quiz2_grade = quiz2;
        quiz3_grade = quiz3;
        exam1_grade = exam1;
        exam2_grade = exam2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, i forgot to add that part but i did define it all initially, i put void in front of the student constructor just now: public void student(String...) and that seemed to fix it but im still unsure if what i did was correct and why it was.

Comment: @Gettin'Stupider No need to be sorry. This was once new for me too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to declare a class, use:

```java
public class student{

//statements;

}
```

else if you are trying to declare a constructor of the class then:

```java
public class student{
  //Parameterized Constructor
  public student(//parameters){
    //body
  }
}
```